# Dart type_test_with_non_type when storing type in variable

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app I want to build this function:

```dart
bool isValidType(element, Type cls) {
  return element is cls;
}
```

The issue with this is: `The name 'cls' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is' expression. Try correcting the name to match an existing type. dart(type_test_with_non_type)`

`element` is dynamic, but I expect it to be an Object of a class that extends the class `Element` (like `class Node extends Element`). The way I want to be able to use this function is:

```
isValidType(node, Node) -> true
isValidType(node, Element) -> true
```

I first thought I could do this:

```dart
bool isValidType(element, Type cls) {
  return element.runtimeType == cls;
}
```

But the problem with that is that for the examples provided above it returns the following:

```
isValidType(node, Node) -> true
isValidType(node, Element) -> false
```

The reason is of course that the `runtimeType` of `node` is `Node` and not `Element`.

What do I have to change in the function provided first to work for my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently isn't much you can do with a `Type` object.  The general recommendation is to avoid using them.

In your case, if you want to check against types known at compilation-time, you could make `isValidType` a generic function instead:

```dart
bool isValidType<T>(dynamic element) => element is T;
```

and then use `isValidType<Node>(node)` or `isValidType<Element>(node)`.  However, I don't think such a function adds anything, so you might as well replace `isValidType<Node>(Node)` with `node is Node` at the callsite.